# getting error in while running Cutom admin controller URL in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, error, dependency-injection

Getting below error -

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Blacklist\Index::_‌​_construct()
>   must be an instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in
>   /home/mage2demo/public_html/mage21new/vendor/magento/framewo‌​rk/ObjectManager/Fac‌​tory/AbstractFactory‌​.php
>   on line 93 and defined in
>   /home/mage2demo/public_html/mage21new/app/code/Namespace\Mod‌​ulename/Controller/A‌​dminhtml/Blacklist/i‌​ndex.php
>   on line 13

here is the code -

```
namespace Mynamespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\ModuleDirectoryname;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $helper;
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \VT\Blacklist\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hello"; die;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried by removing "var/generation" then again run upgrade n compile But result is same.

Comment: Could you post the content of `namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Blacklist\Index.php` please ?

Comment: its above in after "here is the code" section...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code, Replace **`$this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;`** with **`$this->helper = $helper;`**

```
namespace Mynamespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\ModuleDirectoryname;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $helper;
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \VT\Blacklist\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hello"; die;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did  the respective change but same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, **your namespace is wrong**. You should replace:

```
namespace Mynamespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\ModuleDirectoryname;
```

With:

```
namespace Mynamespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Blacklist;
```

Then second problem is that **you assign your helper to a variable that doesn't exist**. Instead of:

```
$this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
```

You should write:

```
$this->helper = $viewHelper;
```

But I **highly doubt those two issues are the cause of your problem**. I suggest you try declaring the `Context` class explicitely in your constructor.

So replace:

```
Context $context
```

With:

```
\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
```

Comment: here is the code -  plz take review -

=========================
`namespace VT\Blacklist\Controller\Adminhtml\Blacklist;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends Action
{
 protected $helper;
 protected $context;
 
 public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \VT\Blacklist\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->viewHelper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hello"; die;
    }
}`

Comment: @Atul did you read my answer at all ? The code you pasted does not show any changes based on my answer

Comment: brother I have made changes in code now . Plz check and let me know what I am still doing wrong -

`namespace VT\Blacklist\Controller\Adminhtml\Blacklist;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
 protected $helper;
 protected $context;
 
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \VT\Blacklist\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hello"; die;
    }
}`

Comment: I just added the Controller file screenshot , plz check. After make upgrade and compile now its redirecting to dashboard. here is the URL   -

http://baseURL/admin/vt_blacklist/blacklist/index/key/a27014efb11eb61262125a3d15925c903ec4fd3a760d0d30e9e588219e13035e/